# How can I change the notification in the Echo Area after org-protocol capture?

Tags: echo-area, message, org-protocol

When capturing something with org-protocol, Emacs displays "item captured" in the Echo Area. Is there any way to change the text that is displayed in the Echo Area?

Comment: It says "Item captured" with a capital `I`: if you search for that string in the Org mode sources, you will see that it is emitted at the end of `org-protocol-capture` and it is hardwired. You would need to modify the function (either by redefining it and changing the string; or perhaps through an after advice, but in that case heed the comment right after the `message` call and remember that `message` returns its argument).